# jquery 3.6.0 animate width to specific size not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xse02qw/8/):

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
  if ($('nav').hasClass('open')) {
    $('nav').removeClass('open');
    $('.hide').animate({
      width: '508px'
    });
  } else {
    $('nav').addClass('open');
    $('.hide').animate({
      width: 'toggle'
    });
  }
})
```

where I'm trying to get a side navbar to just show icons then when the button is clicked to animate to get a specific width.

While the toggling works and it's getting the desired width, it's not animated.

Any ideas?

Comment: what? please explain again

Comment: Your code says "if nav has class open then add class open"  - your `if` is inversed.   https://jsfiddle.net/vtwfeocr/

Comment: Also, you can't animate to a "removed" value

Comment: thanks I updated the question to better explain, also updated jsfiddle to show  the error I'm currently getting

Comment: You'll need to specify the width to animate to

Comment: did I not specify it with `width: '508px'` ? I'm confused

Comment: And what about the other way?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rchoyxe/1/ for some reasons it only animates it the first time,

Comment: "*I specified with 508*" - what about the other way - ie the other width, not just switch the `if` around.   As noted above: you can't animate a "removed"/"auto" value.  So the browser/jquery thinks it's 508, so when you "remove" that with toggle then "toggle" it back on, it's animating from the old value of 508 to the new value of... 508  Fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/k01t7zuy/

Comment: uhm, I'm not sure how but this works, thanks I'll see to import it in my proj. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ck7y19rz/6/

**JavaScript**

```
$('.btn').click(function(event) {
  $("nav").toggleClass("open");
  if ($("nav").hasClass("open")) {
    $(".hide").show().animate({
      width: "580px"
    });
  } else {
    $(".hide").animate({
      width: "0px"
    }, function() {
      $(".hide").hide();
    });
  }
});
```

This is largely just cleaned up code. As was commented, when you animate back to the original size, it must use a Width value, not a keyword, like `auto`. I also added `.show()` and `.hide()` to ensure the state of the element is returned to the expected visible state.